# Location of vm data on xen center

Tags: xen, xenserver

I can't find the vm data (metadata files, disk images) mounted anywhere on the xenserver server. Where is it located, and how can I reach it from dom0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It`s been a while that I played with Citrix XEN.
IMHO it is a castrated RedHat Clone which is trying to hide the details from the SysAdmin.

Try the logical volume manager commands:

```
lvs, lvdisplay, vgdisplay, pvdisplay, ...
```

As far as I remember the citrix xen server uses a LV as disk. So `kpartx -av` applied to the underlying lv-device should add the nodes to /dev so you can access the partitions directly (e.g. by mounting them).